# Lower and Upper bound of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am learning about analysis of algorithms.

I came across the term "upper bound" and "lower bound" in "worst-case" running time of an algorithm.

Are they applicable to only the "worst case" or can be used with other cases also ("average case " and "best case")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are applicable to all cases, but "worst case" is the one most programmers go by because it's just better to always assume the worst case (when designing algorithms).

Comment: So do we consider only the "upper bound" of a "worst case" for analysis of an algorithm?

Comment: @user3902660 Some people only consider that, yes. Often it may be a better idea to think about other cases as well.

Comment: It depends on the kind of program you're working on. If you're working on a real-time system (e.g. hardware control) or to a lesser extent an interactive application, you'll usually focus on minimizing the upper bound/worst case. For systems where high throughput is the goal, e.g. back-end processing systems, "big data"analysis, number crunching and the like, you're more likely to care about the average case.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the *lower bound* is the best case (least amount of work performed) and the *upper bound* is the worst case (most work the algorithm will have to do). Average case is a probabilistic calculation between upper and lower bounds (the result is not necessarily somewhere in the middle, as sometimes the lower bound is potentially rare - or when probability is not simple to establish).

These bounds are useful generally because they narrow down your consideration to "nothing I do can make this particular algorithm perform better than this bound or worse than this one".  So yes, they will be a recurring theme in your future endevours to understand algorithms.

I'd only note that many programs stop dead at worst-case considerations, with just a minor salting of discussion of average-case. It doesn't mean that's all people in various fields consider - it's just all most lower level education classes/books bother to discuss.

Comment: Edited to correct my mistake on mixing up the bounds. Oops! Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Lower and upper bound does not equal best and worst case - big-O is an upper bound that can be used to describe the best, worst or average case. See also: [How does one know which notation of time complexity analysis to use?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57) and [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23068)